# R Extract values from data table given indices stored in another table

Tags: r, vector

I've got a vector (ndx) and table (predict_all)

Vector ndx contains indexes of the predict all table

ndx is as follows:

```
V1 
1  
4  
5  
6
```

the predict_all data table is as follows:

```
V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
0.01 0    0.2  0.4  0.1  0
0.2  0.01 0.1  0.3  0.6  0.3
```

[...]

When I do:
`predict_all[1,1]` I get 0.01 but if I do `predict_all[1, ndx[1]]` I get 1 when I should get 0.01.

just need to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to show the row/column index of the same length.  Here, we are trying to get the value of cell at 1, 1,.  The row index is correct, but column index is a `data.frame` with one column (`ndx[1]` - based on the structure showed in the OP's post).  We need to extract the 'V1' column and get the first element as column index

```
predict_all[1, ndx$V1[1]]
#[1] 0.01
```

NOTE: We assume `predict_all` as a `data.frame`

If it is a `data.table`, then use `with = FALSE`

```
predict_all[1, ndx$V1[1], with = FALSE]
#    V1
#1: 0.01
```

#### data

```
ndx <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), .Names = "V1", 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

predict_all <- structure(list(V1 = c(0.01, 0.2), V2 = c(0, 0.01), 
 V3 = c(0.2, 0.1), V4 = c(0.4, 0.3), V5 = c(0.1, 0.6), 
 V6 = c(0, 0.3)), .Names = c("V1", 
 "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```